# Is this subset of $l_1$ open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0, r>0$. Denote the space $c_{00}^N(\geq 0)$ as:
$$
c_{00}^N( \geq 0) = \{ (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N, 0, ...) \in l^1(\mathbb{R}) : \text{ } x_i \geq 0 \text{ } \forall 1 \leq i \leq N, x_i = 0 \text{ } \forall i > N \}
$$
Define the set $A$ as:
$$
A: = \{ \textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N, 0, ...)  \in c_{00}^N(\geq 0): \text{ } r - a < \sum_{k=1}^N kx_k < r+a \}
$$
The question is whether $A$ is open in $c_{00}^N (\geq 0) $ with respect to the $||.||_1$ norm. My intuition tells me that $A$ should be open. We can rewrite $A$ as
$$
A: = \{ \textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N, 0, ...)  \in c_{00}^N(\geq 0): \text{ } | \sum_{k=1}^N kx_k - r|< a \}
$$
As always we let $B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{x})$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred around $\textbf{x}$, and choose some $\textbf{x}' \in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{x})$ i.e
$$
|| \textbf{x} - \textbf{x}'||_1 = \sum_{k=1}^N |x_k - x_k'| < \epsilon
$$
We want to show that
$$
| \sum_{k=1}^N kx_k' -r| < a
$$
As is usually done I thought we could rewrite the LHS as
$$
| \sum_{k=1}^N k(x_k ' - x_k + x_k) - r|
$$
and apply the triangle inequality a few times, but this seemed to not go anywhere

Comment: Which terms does it make sense to group together? What do you know to be small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ denote a metric space and suppose $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Then, for any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we know by continuity that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $M$.

So, let's take $M := c_{00}^N(\ge 0)$ and equip it with the standard $\ell^1$ norm. This makes $M$ into a metric space. Now, can you find some continuous function from $M$ (with the metric from the $\ell^1$ norm) to $\mathbb{R}$ (with the Euclidean metric) and some open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A = f^{-1}(U)$?

Below is a hint for what to take $f$ to be. Make sure to give the problem a try before checking the hint!

> $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(\mathbf{x}) := \sum_{k=1}^N kx_k$

If you do check this hint, remember that you still have to figure out two things.

1.) What subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ should I choose that is open and is also such that $A = f^{-1}(U)$?

2.) How can I prove that $f$ is continuous from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

If after some attempts you would like some extra hints for 1 and 2, let me know and I will comment below :)

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Choose U = (r-a,r+a) and so f^-1 (U) = A. Continuity of f follows from a standard epsilon-delta exercise. Thank you very much!